# Android Wear: change activity

Tags: android, android-activity, scroll, horizontal-scrolling

I'm developing an Android ( mobile and wear ) application and now, i've a problem.

In the wear module, I've 3 activities and what I want to do is simply to navigate among these 3 activities. 
I'd like to change activity doing an horizontal scroll. It must be similar to the Google Fit app, in which you can swipe left or right to navigate the app.

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a one dimensional `GridViewPager`. It allows you to scroll through a list of *pages*, which might be e.g. `CardFragment`, `Action` or **a custom view**.

Look [here](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/ui/2d-picker.html) to see how it's working. You might also consider to use a `DotsPageIndicator` to give the user a clue, that he might swipe through the content.